# JPA specification with subQuery using filters

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Here I'm using an SQL query to fetch the data, which is working fine. But I want to implement it with JPA specifications.

`select "tab_goal"."goal_id", "goal_name", "goal_name_ar", "customer_id", "start_date", "end_date", "duration_months", "target_sar_amt", "initial_sar_amt", "recurring_sar_amt", "recurring_next_date", "transaction_sar_amt", "conversion_usd_amt", "transit_usd_amt", "investment_balance_amt", "investment_available_amt", "expected_roi_sar_amt", "portfolio_id", "risk_level", "investment_currency_id", "status", (SELECT nvl(SUM("current_price" * "available_qty"),0) FROM "tab_goal_position" gp WHERE gp."goal_id" = "tab_goal"."goal_id" ) "portfolio_amt" from "tab_goal" where rowid in ( select rid from ( select rowid rid from "tab_goal" where "goal_id" = p_goal_id union all select rowid rid from "tab_goal" where "status" = p_status union all select rowid rid from "tab_goal" where "customer_id" = p_customer_id union all select rowid rid from "tab_goal" where "risk_level" = p_risk_level) group by rid having count(*) = nvl2(p_goal_id,1,0) + nvl2(p_status,1,0) + nvl2(p_customer_id,1,0) + nvl2(p_risk_level,1,0) );`

can anyone suggest what to do with JPA specifications ??